# Get frequency of a noisy sample

Tags: sample, frequency

I'm writing you because i mostly need a general algorithm, or even a hint, which i will afterwards port on my system (an embedded Arduino microcontroller);
I have a set of around 650 samples covering 5 seconds representing a periodic signal but with quite a lot of noise;

I need the frequency of the main/dominant signal.
Samples look similar to this https://www.dropbox.com/s/fw196r6yf1awhrh/untitled2.bmp

Here you have a dump with around 5k samples https://www.dropbox.com/s/efwvyn5oec7ixgg/samples.txt

In glad to get any hints on how can i achieve this.
Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 2):

You can just perform a fourier transform and select the highest value, peak as the dominant frequency. Or is there a good reason not to do this?